# Squeryl, inhibitWhen function doesnt seems to work

Tags: scala, squeryl

Im using Squeryl with the function **inhibitWhen** to ignore a **Where** clause when a scala value is Empty. I tried this code but Squeryl still checking for the where clause that i want to ignore!

```
(l.book_id in params.get("book_id").toList.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(_.toInt)).inhibitWhen(params.get("book_id").map(_.isEmpty) == Some(true))
```

So what i need to do is when **book_id** has some values (1,4,6) it use the **in** clause but when it's empty the **in** clause should be ignored !

Comment: The simplest answer is that params.get is returning None, which will produce an empty list in your "in" clause, but won't evaluate to true in your inhibitWhen.

Comment: and what's the simplest solution then ? :)

Comment: In that case, 
.inhibitWhen(params.get("book_id") == None || params.get("book_id").map(_.isEmpty) == Some(true))